# Can I Spread 24-25-4 Fertilizer Before Laying Sod?

Tags: lawn, fertilizer, sod

I will be laying sod in the next week and want to put down fertilizer before. Everything I've read calls for a low-high-high fertilizer mix, but the only "starter" fertilizer at my local big box is 24-25-4.

The lab is further confusing in that it talks up how great it is for spreading before seeding, and that is is also great for sod (but not if it is great before/after laying).

Would such a starter mix more likely hurt the sod laying process?

Comment: That's awfully high nitrogen; I suspect you might burn the roots with it, but I don't know for sure so I'll not make this an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type of grass your sods will contain, but in the UK, I'd only apply what's known as a general purpose fertilizer with an NPK of 7-7-7. Different varieties of grasses may have different requirements, but I'd have thought 24-25-4 unsuitable whatever grass it is.

I've just checked the recommendations for fertilizer beneath buffalo grass sods - it says general purpose, NPK around 5-6-5, so not a lot different.

Comment: One would spread 24-25-5 at roughly one-third the rate (volume) as 7-7-7.  Likewise, one would spread 14-14-14 at one-half the rate as 7-7-7. So,there would be 'no' potash using 24-25-5 = highly undesirable..